# How to convert an exception to error code in Java?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

Let's consider this class :

```
public class Developer {

    public void createApp(DocumentClass requirementsDocuments){
        // some reading, parsing, understanding, planning,....., developping 
        // static methods called here and which might throw exceptions..
    }
}
```

1. I need to modify this class/methods to be able to catch an exception if any is thrown by one of those static methods called in the body of the method `createApp`.
2. And now, I need to create a new method `createAppWithErrorCode` that will return an error code instead of throwing an exception. In other words, I need to convert the exception to an error code :

Let's consider this class :

```
public class ErrorCode {

  private String code;
  private String message;
  // getters and setters..

}
```

Now, How would look the body of this new method added to Developer class :

```
public class Developer {

    public void createApp(DocumentClass requirementsDocuments){
        // ....
    }
    public ErrorCode createAppWithErrorCode(DocumentClass requirementsDocuments){
       // createApp is called here, and if any exception is catched it will be converted into error code       
    }
}
```

Finally, how can we consider the case in which no exception is thrown?

Comment: Homework?  What's the issue?  What have you tried?

Comment: Not a homework. I'm asking for help. Is error handling design not allowed in SO? Thank you.

Comment: Use try/catch to catch the exception.  Based on what you got and where you got it, set an error code and return it.  If no exception or other error return zero or whatever "ErrorCode" value is agreed to mean "no error".  (Is this *that* hard???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll take a crack at it.  You asked for design help, but it's hard to without knowing your requirements.

1. The createApp() method doesn't have a throws clause in the signature, so you're either going to have to catch every checked exception inside that method OR allow unchecked exceptions to bubble out.  Which is closer to meeting your requirement?
2. What should users expect to happen if there's a problem when createApp() is executed?  Feels pretty fundamental.  Should the app shut down with a graceful message?  Is there a way forward if this fails?
3. What does an ErrorCode, which can be ignored, provide that a checked, custom exception does not?  Exceptions are a response to the C return code, which can be ignored.  It feels like you're taking a step back.  I'd prefer custom exceptions with meaningful messages.

Since you've said that it's a web service, I'll offer two other thoughts:

1. You should start with an interface.  Worry more about that and less
   about how you'll expose it to clients.  It'll be easily testable
   that way, because it's a POJO.
2. Forget about the fact that it's a web service.  Get the POJO interface based behavior right and then expose it to clients.  You can change from SOAP to REST to EJB or anything else that way.

Comment: Hello sir. Thank you for this try. In fact, the `createApp` signature can change if throwing exception is necessary, however, `CreateAppWithErrorCode` signature should not change and should not throw any exception. I need to communicate between devices through webservices, and so I need to send that instance of ErrorCode instead of bubbling exceptions... Moreover, this was a constraint and not an option. ErrorCode, cannot be ignored, because if no exception happened, `code` should be set to 0 and `message` to "OK". If a method fail, the app should not shutdown.

Comment: so let the app that wraps the class and expose it as a web service catch those exceptions and marshall what happened into the response XML if SOAP or HTTP if REST